# Indirectly breaking the speed of light

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, event-horizon, faster-than-light

Imagine a system of two objects: a supermassive black hole mass of approximately $10^{36}$ kg and another $1$ kg object revolving around the black hole with an average mean distance of about $1.5×10^{8}$ m. The angular velocity of the smaller object is $2$ rad/s and correspondingly the linear velocity is equal to the speed of light. But how could this be? I know this might be wrong, but where?

Comment: I think the crux of the counterargument might be: "How did the object get there in the first place?" There's no way for an 1kg object to become that close and be moving perpendicular to the black hole.

Comment: For a related example of indirectly breaking the speed of light limit, see the "observable universe size". Objects that are far away enough so the expanding universe makes them move at more than the speed of light are simply unobservable. Just like those inside the event horizon of a black hole.

Comment: To clarify @fraxinus' comment, the objects **still** aren't moving faster than light, within space. What's happening is distance itself is changing - we say that space itself is expanding, and it does so, fast enough to prevent light travelling between them. In effect extra distance is happening in between all objects, and for far enough away objects it happens at a rate that light just cant overcome. This expansion of space itself, isn't limited to the speed of light. But as far as we know, objects in space are limited to that speed

Comment: +1 for an attempt at analysis, however flawed it might be. But what does the word “indirectly” mean in the title?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A black hole of mass $10^{36}$ kg would have a Schwarzschild radius (the distance from the center to the event horizon) of about $1.5\times 10^{9}$ m.

So your choice of "orbital" distance is inside the black hole, and it won't orbit, it will just fall inward.  Outside the event horizon there is a *minimum distance for a stable circular orbit* which is **three times the Schwarzschild radius**.

You cannot use Newtonian physics for these calculations; you need full blown general relativity.  If you try mixing these two systems together you get nonsense.  It is only at distances where the gravitational field is weak that you can apply Newtonian physics with good accuracy.

Regarding why we are so confident that we know what happens inside a black hole (like everything falling inward) when we can never test that directly it comes down to the way the theory is designed.  The theory for what happens outside the event horizon and inside the event horizon are *the same theory* and as we have verified that theory for outside the event horizon to a very, very high level of confidence so there is a very high level of confidence in it's predictions for inside the event horizon.  The basic core the theory of general relativity is that physics must work the same way *everywhere*.  The event horizon doesn't make any difference in this sense.

Comment: But how you are so sure that object will "fall" and not revolve around inside the event horizon? We don't know what's inside a black hole! So....?

Comment: That is a silly complaint. It is a straightforward prediction of the theory that predicts black holes in the first place. Furthermore, it is well away from the region where GR is expected to break down and black hole mergers are consistent with the same theory in a more extreme setting. In any case, we do know that Newtonian gravity does not apply in this scenario.

Comment: The model for outside a black hole also includes the spacetime inside the black hole.  We know it works very well outside, so predictions of what happens inside are considered safe.  What we lack is a theory that is widely accepted that includes gravity and quantum-field-like behaviors, which we would ideally need for the most extreme conditions inside a black hole.  But whether a stable orbit is possible inside is not something we have any doubt on - it's is a well accepted result which we have no reason to doubt (and no way to ever test it I know of).

Comment: @SwayamJha Everything inside the event horizon *must* fall towards the centre. Even light. So if you're falling inside a black hole and shine a laser beam towards the event horizon, those photons also fall towards the centre, they just get there a little bit later than you do.

Comment: @PM2Ring I think even the idea of shining a laser at the event horizon doesn't make sense, because every direction inside the event horizon is pointed towards the center.

Comment: @BlackThorn That's perfectly true, but you can *try* to point the laser towards the EH by pointing it  back the way you came. When you're inside the EH, you can still see some stuff outside the EH... assuming the BH is large enough so you don't get spaghettified before you've even crossed the EH.

Comment: @SwayamJha: General Relativity subsumes Classical Mechanics.  So while it's true that General Relativity hasn't been proven to hold well inside of a black hole, we wouldn't expect General Relativity failing to suggest a reversion to Classical Mechanics.  Rather, we'd probably expect a yet-more-generalized theory to be needed -- one that'd be an even further step away from Classical Mechanics, subsuming GR and CM with it.

Comment: @Dale I don't believe it's a silly complaint. We might theorize all we want using the Schwarzschild solution, but the fact that the inside of the event horizon is de facto unobservable (barring sci-fi applications of certain resolutions of the information paradox I guess) makes it all a mathematical exercise. The inside of a black hole might as well not exist, that wouldn't prevent us from finding solutions to Einstein's equations consistent with the solution outside.

Comment: @user2723984 that doesn’t even apply in this case. The absence of circular orbits begins well outside of the horizon. And the deviations from Newtonian gravity occur even in our own solar system. Furthermore, even if this specific silly objection were limited to inside the EH, your proposed defense doesn’t work in general. All predictions inside the EH are perfectly observable and therefore not merely mathematical exercises. They simply cannot be published to journals outside the EH, but since when do we demand that results must be published outside of the future light cone?

Comment: @Dale I agree it doesn't apply to the original question, but it does to OP's concern in the comment you were replying to. I'm also tempted to agree with the second part of the comment, though I'm not sure how much success it would have on a grant application

Comment: @user2723984 said “I’m not sure how much success it would have on a grant application” Awesome, rebuttal! Made me laugh. +1 for sure

Comment: @Dale While your _point_ in your reply to OP is perfectly valid, calling their objection plain _silly_ makes you sound unnecessarily _arrogant_ - no offence intended, nor do I assume you did; it's just one of those tiny details in communication that we all should avoid ;)

Answer (score 13):

If you imagine a system that breaks the speed of light, it can't exist in reality; simple as that. At gravitational fields that strong, you can't use the Newtonian approximation to determine orbit speeds and must use general relativity instead.

Comment: I have used the equation V=Rw. Where V is linear velocity, R is radius and  w is angukar velocity. Is this equation not valid for that?

Comment: @SwayamJha Newtonian mechanics doesn't work in regions of highly curved spacetime. It's like trying to play pool on the side of a mountain. The pool table needs to be on flat ground, otherwise the balls all roll downhill. ;)

Comment: @SwayamJha you've assumed that the orbital velocity you give is possible though. It is not

Comment: @SwayamJha Most importantly, you have not just used $v=r\omega$, you also calculated the $\omega$ using something -- based on your value for it, I presume you used Newtonian mechanics and that is the first invalid step. Moreover, yes, $v=r\omega$ is also not generally valid in general relativity (however, it would be valid in the case of a Schwarzschild black hole) because the $\theta\theta$ component of the metric might not be just $r^2$, it might be any $f(r,\theta,\phi,t)$.

Comment: @SwayamJha, the answer is _always_ no.  Searching this site will give you an idea how many "attempts" there have been to show otherwise . . . people have been "trying" since 1905.